# ViewHolder getAdapterLocation not getting resolved

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm using RecylerView with ver 25, the build.gradle shows as:

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.1.0'
```

The sdk version is **25.0.1** and all is well, the functionality is working fine. 
Now I am trying to get the position of the item clicked by calling `getAdapterPosition()` inside `onClick` method inside `onBindViewHolder` but it not showing the method.

As i understand the `getAdapterPosition` was introduced in Ver 22 and should work. Please suggest whats wrong.

Comment: You have to perform `getAdapterPosition` on a viewholder instance. `viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()`

Comment: Add code so we can help you.

Comment: so bad of me ! yes it was to be performed on the viewHolder and all the while i have been simply trying to call it directly on the ViewHolder static class !

Answer (score 1):

You can try like it

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(CartViewHolder holder, int position) {
    // Call getAdapterPosition() with holder context 
    holder.getAdapterPosition()
}
```

Comment: yes... this is exactly i did... i was erring in the way i was implementing it

Answer (score 0):

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.activity_display_song_list_fragment, container, false);
        DisplaySongListFragment.ContentAdapter adapter = 
                new DisplaySongListFragment.ContentAdapter(recyclerView.getContext());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    return recyclerView;
}


//Adapter to display recycler view.

public static class ContentAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DisplaySongListFragment.ViewHolder> {


    public ContentAdapter(Context context) {
        con = context;
        ReadFileFromSDCard();
    }
    @Override
    public DisplaySongListFragment.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new DisplaySongListFragment.ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()), parent);
    }

    // pass view holder object to method.
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(DisplaySongListFragment.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        HashMap<String, String> song = new HashMap<String, String>();
        song = songsList.get(position);

        holder.name.setText(song.get(DisplaySongListFragment.KEY_artistName));
        holder.description.setText(song.get(DisplaySongListFragment.KEY_trackCensoredName));
        Glide.with(con).load(song.get(DisplaySongListFragment.KEY_artworkUrl30)).into(holder.avator);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return songsList.size();
    }
}

static Context con;

// provide layout to list row
public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public ImageView avator;
    public TextView name;

    public TextView description;
    public ViewHolder(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent) {
        super(inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_list, parent, false));
        avator = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_avatar);
        name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_title);
        description = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_desc);
        // Pass the selected Item Position to another activity.
        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Context context = v.getContext();
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, DetailActivity.class);
               intent.putExtra(DetailActivity.EXTRA_POSITION, getAdapterPosition());
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```